# React Simple Compont is not rendering inside the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi have create a sample function and called inside the RenderDOM

But seeing in the brower end the output is not showing

Do anyone have any suggestion

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function wwhello(){
  return <div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          <p>Summa</p>
        </div>;
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <wwhello/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What is wrong with this code

Comment: Could you provide your `index.html` file?

Comment: are you sure that you have element with id root in your html?

<div id="root"></div>

Comment: React component names use PascalCasing. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**React component needs to be in capitalizing first letter:**

You can see it in the log error:

```
Warning: The tag <wwhello> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
    at wwhello
```

**So change it to:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Wwhello(){
  return <div>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>Summa</p>
         </div>;
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Wwhello/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-roentgen-djj32?file=/src/index.js  was checking the exact same so why not provide the link i guess

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to use the parantheses correctly when returning your markup

```
return (
   <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <p>Summa</p>
   </div>
)
```

other than that, always start your components name with a capital letter

Comment: issue was the missing capital letter

Answer (score 1):

Components in React should start with a capital letter.

From the react docs:

> **Note: Always start component names with a capital letter.**
>
> React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags. For example, `<div />` represents an HTML div tag, but `<Welcome />` represents a component and requires `Welcome` to be in scope.
>
> To learn more about the reasoning behind this convention, please read
> [JSX In Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).